# for List<String> i want to add first default value as ALL

Tags: java, list

This query return a list of batchfilename.

> this is my method in implementation class

```
List<String> resultList = this.getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(" SELECT distinct FILE_NAME FROM tab1 union SELECT DISTINCT FILE_NAME FROM tab2 order by file_name asc",String.class);

resultList.addFirst(AppConstants.DEFAULT);
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: and ..., any problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addFirst()` is defined in `LinkedList` class and not `List` interface. One option is that you can create new `LinkedList` object and copy all elements there.

```
List resultList = this.getJdbcTemplate().queryForList (" SELECT distinct FILE_NAME FROM tab1 union SELECT DISTINCT FILE_NAME FROM tab2 order by file_name asc",String.class);   

LinkedList newList = new LinkedList(resultList);
newList.addFirst(AppConstants.DEFAULT);
```

Or you can add your default value to your list first and use `list.addAll()` to add all the remaining values...

```
List resultList = new ArrayList();
resultList.add(AppConstants.DEFAULT);
resultList.addAll(this.getJdbcTemplate().queryForList (" SELECT distinct FILE_NAME FROM tab1 union SELECT DISTINCT FILE_NAME FROM tab2 order by file_name asc",String.class));
```